# Documenting class extension in objective c using doxygen

Tags: ios, doxygen, doxygen-wizard

I have an objective-C class with a class extension in the implementation file. This class extension contains a property. When I run doxygen, in the output I don't see the property that was declared in the class extension. I only see the properties declared in the main header file.

I am running doxygen version 1.8.2, which is supposed to support class extensions in objective C. Do you know what I could be doing wrong in terms of configuration?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The extension was not listed under the class name in the class index, but under ClassName(Private), I just missed it.